# как поменять первый и последний элементы в бинарном файле си

Tags: c

К примеру, у нас есть три числа a,b,c.  На выходе необходимо получить c,d,a.
Как это сделать с помощью прямого доступа я понимаю, а вот как с использованием seek_set seek_end не совсем.. 
Каким образом это можно реализовать с помощью вышеупомянутых функций?

Comment: Вы уверены, что **внимательно** прочли [man fseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)? Если да, то что конкретно мешает вам сначала прочесть первые  и последние sizeof(тип-вашего-числа) байт в память, а потом записать их?

Comment: А что именно аы имеете в виду под "прямым достуром"?

Comment: @Jessi_Marilot Цитирую: "есть  **a,b,c**" и "необходимо **c,d,a**"... Это как ?!!!